# PDOException: SQLSTATE 01002 Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Tags: php, laravel, freetds, sqlsrv, unixodbc

I have been following some answers over stackoverflow.

My odbc. ini (located in /etc/odbc.ini)

```
[MSSQL]
Description = MS SQL Server
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Server = host.of.the.server
UID = myusername
PWD = mypassword
ReadOnly = No
Port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

My odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS driver
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
UsageCount = 1
```

Both of these files are empty at first. I just copied answer from the other threads.

My freetds.conf

```
# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 8.0

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 8.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

I am using Laravel. Now, after I used the

```
php artisan migrate
```

I got an error of:  PDOException:  SQLSTATE 01002 Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Some of stackoverflow answers: possbile cause is TDS version.

So I used `tsql -C`

```
    Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 5.0
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
```

I am Using Ubuntu 16

Comment: Does EasySoft-ODBC Driver will solve my whole problem?  http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the TDS version to 7.0 or 8.0 and ensure that you have the following packages installed -

```
php5-sybase 
php5-odbc
```

Comment: how to change my TDS version. I've already edited all the .ini files.

Comment: Your freetds.conf file is displaying the version as 8.0 but when you run tsql -C the TDS version is listed at 5.0 Are you sure that tds is referencing the correct freetds.conf file? This link my help - [freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm)

Comment: Also, to future-proof, you'll want to use TDS Version 7.1, *not* 8.0. Never use 8.0, it is a deprecated value which will be removed from FreeTDS.

Comment: Good advice. I wasn't aware 8.0 was being depreciated.